# Why the arg0 in android listview is not update incrementally?

Tags: android, android-listview

I am previously working on PHP and js , and recently I am working on android listview
However, I encountered a problem in creating a custom adapter for listview

```
public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
        // TODO
        if (arg1 == null) {
            arg1 = myInflater.inflate(R.layout.grid, arg2, false);
        }
        TextView name = (TextView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.text1);
        TextView desc = (TextView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.text2);
        ImageView image = (ImageView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.image1);
        if (arg0 < images.length) {
            image.setImageResource(images[arg0]);
        }
        name.setText(names[arg0]);
        // name.setText(arg0);
        // desc.setText(images.length);
        desc.setText(description[arg0]);
        return arg1;
    }
```

The problem is I have 3 array of content to pass to the listview grid, for the first two array, there are 10 element and the last one have 3 only. So , it is out of boundries for the last one. I added a condition to check whether it exceed 3 , but args0 seems not increased according to the row?

```
if (arg0 < images.length) {
                image.setImageResource(images[arg0]);
            }
```

The first three row and some other rows also has image setted,  why is that and how to fix this? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all, correctly you do use "image.length()" instead of your "image.length".

second, if you check
[Android Developer for ImageView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html),
you will figure that there is no such method like .length() for an ImageView.

my first guess is, that you mix up the ArrayList containing your values with your ImageView, that is just for displaying purposes.